Do you need assembler to enhance the performance of your algorithm?
for an IT-Project in school I'm developing a sponge constrction (doesn't have to be secure but it has to mix well) and I'm done implementing it in Python,however it is extremely slow and I don't really know how to speed it up.
Maybe using assembler is an option,but if I'm honest I have no clue how to use it, maybe you can convert Python to Assembler somehow,but I wouldn't know...
If anyone knows a few techniques to speed up my mixing and extraction algorithms that I will show below, or has something I can read to get information I would be extremely thankful for anyone that extends a helping hand.
PS: do you all know assembler well and can implement your algorithms in it or is it just a misconception of mine? :D
And yes,I speak german,if anybody has any questions concerning the comments of my code,please let me know!
import time

tab = [129, 160, 71, 24, 142, 254, 178, 152, 182, 53, 190, 133, 149, 187, 56, 14, 198, 62, 192, 118, 121, 125, 4, 146, 90, 207, 66, 31, 19, 7, 132, 114, 68, 202, 208, 80, 37, 40, 134, 58, 111, 42, 250, 105, 180, 41, 156, 155, 166, 211, 170, 215, 165, 69, 88, 23, 6, 141, 226, 186, 35, 28, 54, 193, 89, 92, 230, 120, 44, 59, 64, 237, 151, 91, 116, 171, 87, 115, 26, 137, 67, 78, 194, 5, 29, 167, 189, 17, 253, 124, 238, 65, 184, 30, 185, 220, 84, 172, 123, 174, 18, 117, 153, 150, 128, 74, 162, 98, 212, 231, 159, 242, 206, 93, 188, 46, 76, 243, 147, 240, 219, 179, 139, 246, 255, 130, 195, 99, 161, 183, 245, 22, 140, 45, 173, 163, 148, 33, 20, 47, 216, 131, 12, 72, 223, 32, 145, 94, 249, 96, 205, 10, 157, 57, 95, 136, 138, 218, 229, 0, 122, 107, 126, 113, 109, 127, 158, 168, 210, 236, 204, 112, 191, 252, 104, 48, 73, 79, 197, 52, 108, 176, 38, 102, 100, 164, 247, 61, 2, 241, 43, 224, 119, 75, 63, 25, 143, 225, 97, 217, 106, 203, 110, 49, 200, 1, 39, 233, 3, 214, 81, 209, 60, 244, 34, 154, 239, 9, 101, 232, 235, 85, 83, 50, 86, 169, 51, 222, 201, 175, 144, 135, 16, 70, 248, 15, 82, 234, 27, 228, 8, 55, 21, 221, 36, 196, 177, 77, 227, 199, 213, 13, 251, 11, 103, 181]
#inv_tab = [159, 205, 188, 208, 22, 83, 56, 29, 240, 217, 151, 253, 142, 251, 15, 235, 232, 87, 100, 28, 138, 242, 131, 55, 3, 195, 78, 238, 61, 84, 93, 27, 145, 137, 214, 60, 244, 36, 182, 206, 37, 45, 41, 190, 68, 133, 115, 139, 175, 203, 223, 226, 179, 9, 62, 241, 14, 153, 39, 69, 212, 187, 17, 194, 70, 91, 26, 80, 32, 53, 233, 2, 143, 176, 105, 193, 116, 247, 81, 177, 35, 210, 236, 222, 96, 221, 224, 76, 54, 64, 24, 73, 65, 113, 147, 154, 149, 198, 107, 127, 184, 218, 183, 254, 174, 43, 200, 161, 180, 164, 202, 40, 171, 163, 31, 77, 74, 101, 19, 192, 67, 20, 160, 98, 89, 21, 162, 165, 104, 0, 125, 141, 30, 11, 38, 231, 155, 79, 156, 122, 132, 57, 4, 196, 230, 146, 23, 118, 136, 12, 103, 72, 7, 102, 215, 47, 46, 152, 166, 110, 1, 128, 106, 135, 185, 52, 48, 85, 167, 225, 50, 75, 97, 134, 99, 229, 181, 246, 6, 121, 44, 255, 8, 129, 92, 94, 59, 13, 114, 86, 10, 172, 18, 63, 82, 126, 245, 178, 16, 249, 204, 228, 33, 201, 170, 150, 112, 25, 34, 211, 168, 49, 108, 250, 209, 51, 140, 199, 157, 120, 95, 243, 227, 144, 191, 197, 58, 248, 239, 158, 66, 109, 219, 207, 237, 220, 169, 71, 90, 216, 119, 189, 111, 117, 213, 130, 123, 186, 234, 148, 42, 252, 173, 88, 5, 124]

#for i in range(len(tab)): inv_tab[tab[i]] = i
#print(inv_tab)



def subbytes(matrix):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix)):
            matrix[i][j] = tab[matrix[i][j]]

    return matrix

#def inv_subbytes(matrix):
    #for i in range(len(matrix)):
        #for j in range(len(matrix)):
            #matrix[i][j] = inv_tab[matrix[i][j]]

    #return matrix


def mix_rows_gerade_runde(matrix):#(mixRows in even rounds)
    #MixRowsgerade_runde([byte0,byte1,byte2,byte3]) -> [(byte0 ⊕ 0xD3),(byte0 ⊕ byte1 ⊕ 0xD3),(byte0 ⊕ byte1 ⊕ byte2 ⊕ 0xD3),(byte0 ⊕ byte1 ⊕ byte2 ⊕ byte3 ⊕ 0xD3)]
    rk = 0xd3
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        matrix[i] = [(matrix[i][0]^rk),(matrix[i][0]^matrix[i][1]^rk),(matrix[i][0]^matrix[i][1]^matrix[i][2]^rk),(matrix[i][0]^matrix[i][1]^matrix[i][2]^matrix[i][3]^rk)]
        rk += 1
    return matrix

def mixRowsungerade_runde(matrix):#(mixRows in odd rounds)[byte0,byte1,byte2,byte3]) -> [(byte0 ⊕ byte1 ⊕ byte2 ⊕ byte3 ⊕ 0xD3),(byte1 ⊕ byte2 ⊕ byte3 ⊕ 0xD3),(byte2 ⊕ byte3 ⊕ 0xD3),(byte3 ⊕ 0xD3)]
    #MixRowsgerade_runde([byte0,byte1,byte2,byte3]) -> [(byte0 ⊕ 0xD3),(byte0 ⊕ byte1 ⊕ 0xD3),(byte0 ⊕ byte1 ⊕ byte2 ⊕ 0xD3),(byte0 ⊕ byte1 ⊕ byte2 ⊕ byte3 ⊕ 0xD3)]
    rk = 0xd3
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        matrix[i] = [(matrix[i][-4]^matrix[i][-3]^matrix[i][-2]^matrix[i][-1]^rk),(matrix[i][-3]^matrix[i][-2]^matrix[i][-1]^rk),(matrix[i][-2]^matrix[i][-1]^rk),(matrix[i][-1]^rk)]
        rk += 1
    return matrix

def shift_colums(matrix):
    return [
        [matrix[0][0],matrix[3][1],matrix[2][2],matrix[1][3]],
        [matrix[1][0],matrix[0][1],matrix[3][2],matrix[2][3]],
        [matrix[2][0],matrix[1][1],matrix[0][2],matrix[3][3]],
        [matrix[3][0],matrix[2][1],matrix[1][2],matrix[0][3]]
    ]


def status_matrix_xor(m1,m2):
    for i in range(len(m1)):
        for j in range(len(m1[i])):
            m1[i][j]^=m2[i][j]
    return m1

status = [[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],#r ist hier
          [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
          [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
          [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
          [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
          [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
          [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
          [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
          [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
          [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
          [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
          [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
          [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]]

def prp(block):
    for i in range(3):
        block = subbytes(block)
        block = mix_rows_gerade_runde(block)
        block = shift_colums(block)
    for i in range(2):
        block = subbytes(block)
        block = mixRowsungerade_runde(block)
        block = shift_colums(block)
    block = mixRowsungerade_runde(block)
    block = subbytes(block)
    return block

def status_permutieren():
    global status
    status[0] = prp(status[0])
    for i in range(1,len(status)):
        status[i] = status_matrix_xor(status[i],status[i-1])
        status[i] = prp(status[i])

def absorbiere_block(block):
    status[0] = status_matrix_xor(status[0],block)
    status_permutieren()

def daten_absorbieren(daten:list):
    while(len(daten) % 16 != 0):
        daten.append(0)
    for i in range(0,len(daten),16):
        block = [[daten[i],daten[i+1],daten[i+2],daten[i+3]],[daten[i+4],daten[i+5],daten[i+6],daten[i+7]],[daten[i+8],daten[i+9],daten[i+10],daten[i+11]],[daten[i+12],daten[i+13],daten[i+14],daten[i+15]]]
        absorbiere_block(block)

def NFSR():
    global status
    return(((status[0][3][2]^~status[4][1][0]|status[10][2][3])^(status[7][0][1]^~status[9][2][2])^~(status[11][2][3]&status[1][3][0]))%256)

def daten_extrahieren(laenge):
    daten = []
    for i in range(laenge):
        daten.append(NFSR())
        status_permutieren()
    return daten

def daten_generieren(seed,laenge):
    global status
    daten = []
    daten_absorbieren(seed)
    daten = daten_extrahieren(laenge)
    status = [
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],#r ist hier
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]]
    return daten


def text_als_seed(text,länge):
    global status
    a = [ord(text[i]) for i in range(len(text))]

    daten_absorbieren(a)

    a = daten_extrahieren(länge)

    status = [[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],#r ist hier
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]]

    return a
```


Does your S-box have a particular structure to it, or did you select a random permutation?  Two of the accelerated implementations of AES take advantage of how it is an inversion operation in $GF(256)$ combined with a binary affine transform.

I would be great to get some indication of how much faster an assembled primitive can run compared to good optimised C code.

@PaulUszak i generally get a 20% speed up with assembly with C entries.  this is not for cryptography but general mathematics

My experience is that I can usually beat assembly code in C or C++. That's because writing C or C++ is much less work, so you can do optimisations that you don't have the time to do yourself in assembler.

@gnasher729 optimization in the assembly has only a limit of machine capabilities, compilers on the other hand, are the limit of their designer. I"ve seen so much optimization that the compiler can never execute.

Yes, in theory assembler can always be at least as fast, assuming that you can create any code that a compiler can generate. In practice however I'd bet that C is often more performant - although I assume it depends on the algorithm as well.

I'd say that most cryptographic primitive implementations are not performed in assembly, let alone fully implemented in assembly as you can of course mix it with e.g. C code. I'd say that though that assembly / optimized C are fastest, Java and bytecode is about twice as slow and higher level scripting languages are much much slower - those usually use wrapper libraries around e.g. OpenSSL to speed things up. Note that the general speed indications for "business logic" in PLs often do not translate to these closely nit algorithms.

@kekalaka and if seen a hardcoded loop using SIMD registers in assembler with lots of work, so I rewrote it in C, and then copy/paste eight times and the last five seconds of work made it a lot faster. Can’t do that in assembler.  Given a task X and a time T to produce correct code, C is almost always faster. And in C you can look at the algorithm and figure out a faster way quickly. In eight hours you might have written code for algorithm A, and slightly faster B, C and D while in assembler you have a slightly better implementation of A.

Even in Python, there are some avenues for significant optimization; at least:

Making as many state transformations as possible by stating offsets into a single instance of the state,
and (that goes together) turning the status from a table of 13 tables of 4 tables of 4 bytes into a table of 208 bytes. The existing representation may be a nice way to express the algorithm to a human, but computers are not human.
When expressions are constants (like many of lengths), use constants.
Unrolling inner loops and function calls that can be.

Independently, a huge speed benefit is possible by rewriting the code in a language that compiles to native code: C, C++, Go, Rust to name some likely to give the fastest executable. Even a Python compiler can be of some (lesser) help.
For this kind of algorithm, assembly will typically not give a worthwhile improvement over a competent C implementation. At least it's not reasonable to move from Python directly to assembly for the sake of performance.

We are in cryptography, not in performance optimization. For us, side-channel secure is more important. The question and the answer, as of currently don't belong cyptography.se

@kelalaka Cryptographers are very much concerned about the performance of algorithms and implementations. Things that are slow don't get used. In fact, there seems to be a trend of prioritising performance over security in many cases, like BLAKE3 and KangarooTwelve reducing the number of rounds, using non-collision resistant MACs, favouring non-misuse resistant AEADs, etc.

@samuel-lucas6 neither the question nor the answer mention ask/mention about it. As Thomas Pornin has indicated in their pages the compilers are unreliable for side channel secure code, and writing full assembly has other problems. So, they invented a new language for this. I'm happy to hear about it. Besides this is sponge, as long as it is not KMAC where it is related to secure coding? This is just a programming question asked about whether should I use ASM or Python.

Of course, cryptographers are searching about reducing their rounds etc, time is money and the secure and fast will be the winner. This question/answer is not on topic, IMHO. We are opening a flooding question with this..
